# Are there any known problems installing Development Edition MS SQL Server Aside SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have an application running on SQL Express SQL 9.0. Are there any known problems installing a Development Edition of MS SQL Server 2008 R2 along side SQL Express? In other words, is there a known problem having two different flavors of SQL Server installed? Is the Development edition treated like a second instance?

I know you can have multiple instances of SQL Server, with only one instance allowed as the unnamed or default instance. I'm just curious if anyone knows of a gotcha.

Thanks.

Comment: Point taken. I edited the question's title and body to reflect what I'm trying to do.

Comment: There could be issues with the ports that the two SQLs would use

Comment: This may help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-servers.html

Comment: @JakeElsley  I somehow doubt a doc on MySQL will be of much use to someone with MSSQL server, actually.

Comment: Sorry I seem to have mis-read the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the normal cautions and warnings about a side-by-side SQL installation, there are no "known issues" as a result of doing a side-by-side installation between SQL Express 9 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

[This guy's done it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/3031e486-8507-4261-81b5-bc6b67151598/) without issue, as have I, though with different versions.  Pretty sure it was SQL Express 2005 and SQL 2008 (100)/R1 in my case.

EDIT:

Since you've updated the question, I'll do the same... the Developer Edition will be treated exactly like a second instance (because that's what it is), and the general use-case of a side-by-side MSSQL installation *is* to have different versions of MSSQL.  Because, for example, in my case, our #$^@ing employee time-keeping software is shackled to MSSQL 2000, while the rest of the world has moved on, and requires a higher version of MSSQL.  So one of our [production] SQL servers has MSSQL 2000 and MSSQL 2008 on it in a side-by-side installation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying not to screw up a production environment running Wasp Barcode Inventory Control. Since it's a public works server and we're short of SQL server space, I've got a license that will cover two people.

Comment: Just another point but remember the developer edition is not licensed for production use (last time I checked).  SQL Express however is.